# Is this a comma splice? If not, why?

Tags: punctuation

It's not important, I just thought you should know.

and

It's not important, I just thought you would like to know about the phonecall.

Comment: What research have you done on the question?

Comment: "Comma splice" finds 155 results in search.  It's been three hours.  Where are the members of The Committee for the Promotion of Virtue and the Prevention of Vice?

Answer (score 2):

> "It's not important, I just thought you should know."

and

> "It's not important, I just thought you would like to know about the phone call."

are both comma splices, as you suspected. In each case, the comma should be replaced with a semicolon, *except in informal writing including personal email,* where the use of a comma would be considered acceptable.

Comment: Thank you so much! The informality of email is perhaps why I was so confused. I so often see completely competent writers email in this informal way and question everything I know.

Comment: Well @Mark, **you** might consider a comma acceptable in email.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but I  doubt it is any more or less erroneous in informal contexts, so much as it is that just that we are supposed to be generally more tolerant of simple errors in those contexts. It seems particularly odd to except emails, since, at least on the standard qwerty layout, the semicolon is a home key. You would be putting in extra effort just to splice the comma in that case unless you did not know of a better way to do it. (This is not meant to imply that I think  I make good use of commas myself or am never guilty of run-on sentences.)